# How to sort by custom field?

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

In my custom post type ("mitarbeiter") there is a custom field called "sort" which only allows numbers as value. Currently my posts are getting ordered by the title. I would like to order them by the value of the custom field "sort" which will be given by the function `get_field("sort")`.

This is how my code looks for now:

```
// Get the team members
function get_employee() {
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'mitarbeiter',
        'showposts' => 100,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $content = '
            <div class="col-md-6 department member_of_'. get_field("abteilung") .'">
                <div class="well">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-5">';
                            // Display the image
                            $image = get_field('portraitfoto');
                            if (!empty($image)) :
                                $content .= '<img class="img-responsive sidebar-img team-member" src="'. $image["url"] .'" alt="'. $image["alt"] .'" /><br />';
                            endif;
                        $content .= '</div>
                        <!-- /.col-xs-5 -->
                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                            <h2>'. get_the_title() .'</h2>
                            <p>'. get_field("funktion") .'<br>'.
                             get_field("telefon") . '<br>
                            <a href="mailto:'. get_field("email") . '">'. get_field("email") .'</a></p>
                        </div><!-- /.col-xs-7 -->
                    </div><!-- /.row -->
                </div><!-- /.well -->
            </div><!-- /.col-md-6 -->';

    echo $content;
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: **NEVER EVER** use `query_posts`. Also, see documentation of `WP_Query`, and do a little research, there are so much info on this very subject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pieter mentioned in a comment, `query_posts()` isn't the best function to use - see [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts) on WordPress Stack Exchange for some background on this. Basically, it's inefficient and causes some obscure bugs.

The better way to do this would be using [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and that documentation shows you how to do this as well as quite a lot more (it's a pretty powerful class).

To rewrite your query, and add your sorting criteria, you'd be looking at something like this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array( 
  'post_type' => 'mitarbeiter',
  'posts_per_page' => 100,
  'meta_key' => 'sort',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'ASC',
) );
```

To make your loop work with your custom WP_Query, you'll need to also change this line:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

to this:

```
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
```

and change the `wp_reset_query();` call at the end of your code to `wp_reset_postdata();`

You should find this sorts by the `sort` meta key for you, as well as makes sure your page runs a bit faster.

Comment: My pleasure! Really glad it helped =]

Answer (score 1):

used `meta_key`  in `query_posts`and `orderby = 'meta_value_num'`

```
query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'mitarbeiter',
        'showposts' => 100,
        'meta_key'          => 'sort',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'ASC/DESC'// Add ASC OR DESC as per your requirement 
) );
```